# Is it possible: array in record

Tags: arrays, delphi, record

I have next arrays

```
NAMES1: array[0..1] of string = ('NO1','NAME1');
NAMES2: array[0..1] of string = ('NO2','NAME2');
```

and a record structure

```
TMyRec = record(
  Name: ????;
);
```

As result I need to declare a constant array of records like following

```
const
  StringArraysList: array[0..1] of TMyRec = (
    (Name: NAMES1),
    (Name: NAMES2)
  );
```

The question is what type should I select for Name in TMyRec?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to do it like this:

```
type
  TTwoNames = array[0..1] of string;

  TMyRec = record
    Names: TTwoNames;
  end;

const
  StringArraysList: array[0..1] of TMyRec = (
    (Names: ('NO1','NAME1')),
    (Names: ('NO2','NAME2'))
  );
```

---

You would prefer to write the final declaration as

```
const
  NAMES1: TTwoNames = ('NO1','NAME1');
  NAMES2: TTwoNames = ('NO2','NAME2');

  StringArraysList: array[0..1] of TMyRec = (
    (Names: NAMES1),
    (Names: NAMES2)
  );
```

But that results in

> [DCC Error] Unit1.pas(38): E2026 Constant expression expected

Some Delphi constants are not as constant as you would like them to be!

The documentation for [record constants](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declared_Constants#Record_Constants) states that

> The values must be represented by constant expressions.

The documentation for [typed constants](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declared_Constants#Typed_Constants) states that

> Typed constants cannot occur in constant expressions.

Put these two rules together and we have `E2026`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What about case when I'll need new array which dimension differs. Like following: NAMES3: array[0..2] of string = ('NO3','NAME3', 'SMTH ELSE'); Thus I can't declare TTwoNames as array of two elements.

Comment: Then you can't do it as a constant at all. Then you need a dynamic array that you assign at runtime.

Comment: I always tend to see "true constants" as "named literals", i.e. they are just symbolic replacements for literals.

Comment: @Yura: If you want to use dynamic arrays, you can, at runtime, use SetLength and then set each item one by one, but you can also do: `MyArray := TStringDynArray.Create('NO3', 'NAME3', 'SMTH ELSE');` using the constructor syntax for dynarrays.

Answer (score 5):

You could declare a new type

```
TName = array[0..1] of string;
```

and use that in your record declaration.
Your declaration then becomes

```
type
  TName = array[0..1] of string;

  TMyRec = record
    Name: TName;
  end;

const
  StringArraysList: array[0..1] of TMyRec = (
    (Name: ('NO1','NAME1')),
    (Name: ('NO2','NAME2'))
  );
```